# Mystery HTTP 400 Bad Request

Tags: google-chrome, http, firefox, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I'm testing a deployed Azure web app using Firefox latest. I am using developer tools and keep finding the following message:

```
POST https://westus-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com//v2/track [HTTP/2 400 Bad Request 1542ms]
```

[image: App Insights entry last line]

But I am not using Azure Application Insights. I have done so during development. But **I don't have this service enabled** in any resource group of my Azure subscription now. The app is performing well. This is the only 'error' that I am getting.

This shows in Chrome (latest) developer tools:

[image: App Insights chrome dev]

Given that I'm new to this. Can anyone explain this output? I find the 1542ms a little concerning. If this request is being made regularly then will this slow down the app operations? I've got database functionality for logging in and storing data.

I haven't been able to find anyone else who has posted about this kind of thing.

Adding project file details here (with edits)

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-rollbase-6D7D2449-EB25-45CE-A8D3-EDAB69CDCAB3</UserSecretsId>
    <RootNamespace></RootNamespace>
    <RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>false</RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>
    <AssemblyName />
    <PackageId />
    <EnableNETAnalyzers>false</EnableNETAnalyzers>
  </PropertyGroup>

// many Removes here

    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="bootstrap" Version="5.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="5.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.11">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.11">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration" Version="4.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

 
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\ServiceDependencies\" />
  </ItemGroup>

 
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Views\Entries\Create.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Entries\Delete.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Entries\Details.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Entries\Edit.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Entries\Index.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I should say that I have tried clearing cookies. But I think the bad requests are originating server side so I didn't expect cookies to make any difference. I am not aware of anything I can do on the Azure side.

Comment: The error says that Application Insights (AI) Instrumentation key used in the solution is incorrect. Because of this AI is not able to log usage information in it. If you are not leverage usage tracking, then  use the Key as "NA"

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT As I said in my question. I am no longer using Application Insights. I don't have any reference to Application Insights in my code.

Comment: Could you please share your. csproj file.

Comment: Have shared .csproj file as requested.

Comment: I have re-enabled Application Insights in Azure portal for the deployed app. Now I don't get the above HTTP 400 error in browser dev tools. Before I did this I looked at the app configuration settings. I noticed APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING was still present (even though Application Insights was not enabled at this time) This connection string contains this address  https://westus-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/ which is showing in the HTTP 400 Browser error. I will delete this setting when I finish using Application Insights. I have a good feeling this will stop the errors.